# Is there a css @media query that can identify a landscape or portrait display?

Tags: css, screen-orientation, media-queries

I am trying to create a media query to identify if a screen is landscape or portrait so that I can change the CSS styling when a screen is rotated. Is this possible and how would i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [`orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation) feature.

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    /* ... */
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Side note, this question definitely belongs on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead since it's implementation-specific.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works well! Thanks also for guidance on StackOverflow - new to a lot of this so will check it out.